# How to make R skip for 2:n cycle in case n = 1?

Tags: r, range

I have the next query.
I have a cycle

```
for (i in 2:n) { ... }
```

and it executes twice in case n = 1 for i equals 2 and then for 1, but I want this cycle isn't been executed at all in such case.
I've also tried

```
seq(from = 2, to = 1, by = 1)
```

but it generates exception.

I guess than common question, but I am new in that language and wasn't able to bypass it or find workaround in internet.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `:` or `seq` don't work that way. You could use the `length.out` param in seq: `seq(from = 2, to = n,length.out = (n-2)+1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `seq_len`  which is safer to use

```
n <- 1
for (i in seq_len(n)[-1]) {
  cat("Check", i, "\n")
}

#Does not print anything

n <- 4
for (i in seq_len(n)[-1]) {
  cat("Check", i, "\n")
}

#Check 2 
#Check 3 
#Check 4
```

When you use `2:n` and when `n = 1` it gives

```
2:1
#[1] 2 1
```

hence, it runs the loop twice.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. It should be `seq_len(n-1) + 1`.